# Swift sending request not responding

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

So Im in the early stages of learning swift, and I'm trying to make a trivial class to wrap the process of sending/retrieving data from a given web service. The issue I'm having is that nothing is printing to console after I have sent the request, or any kind of response for that matter. I would really appreciate any help or guidance as to what I am doing wrong

```
import Foundation

class URLHelper : NSObject,NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate{

var data = NSMutableData()


func sendReq(){
    let urlPath: String = "http://localhost/web-service/action.php?callback=showUserDetails&uid=1"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url,cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 4)
    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!

    connection.start()
}


func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    self.data.appendData(data)
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    println(error.description)
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    var err: NSError
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
    println(jsonResult)
}


}


var req = URLHelper()   
req.sendReq()
```

## **UPDATE**

```
<?php



//Get the action to run the coorect request
if(isset($_GET['callback'])){
        $function = $_GET['callback'];
        call_user_func($function);
        //$function();
}else{
    echo "Error: No valid callback supplied to request";
}


function showUserDetails(){ 
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "service_db") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn)); 
    $userid = $_GET['uid'];
    $results = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $userid")); 
    mysqli_close($conn);

    echo json_encode($results);

}


if($db->connect_errno > 0){
  die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
 }

?>
```

The returned json is as follows `{"id":"1","username":"tom","email":"tom_smith@gmail.com"}`

Comment: set `timeoutInterval` for your `request`, and then try. Everything seems good and your code is calling `delegate` methods too.

Comment: @arthankamal I have but still its not printing the contents of the response. I debugged and after the connection.start the program ends and console says program exited with 0.

Comment: Check ur delegates calling or not, if it's calling then check your JSON is valid or not

Comment: None of my delegates get called ? I stepped through each line and after the connection.start nothing else gets fired. Why is that ? Shouldn't the `self` set the delegate. The json is valid because when I attempted it with objective c it worked

Comment: i tried your code with `google.com`, it's working fine in my system, except it's crashing in `JSON serializing`

Comment: So it actually runs the delegate methods for you ? That's strange is there something I am missing , an additional method? I tried g`google` as well but it compiles and runs

Comment: Do you have a server log that shows the request arriving and some response being returned from it? (Or server-side error...)

Comment: Yes I do if requesting from localhost but what I don't understand is why none of the event handlers are being triggered. Shouldn't the `didFail` function be called ? even if i send a request to `google` the `didfinishedloading` function is never called

Comment: You aren't checking the error - you should pass in &err instead of 'nil' and then verifying what has happened. That said, I'm not sure having the data in the member variable is something you wanted to do here.

I've published Swift Essentials at http://swiftessentials.org, and I cover network data - the source is at https://github.com/alblue/com.packtpub.swift.essentials which has some network code e.g. https://github.com/alblue/com.packtpub.swift.essentials/blob/master/RepositoryBrowser/RepositoryBrowser/NSURLExtensions.swift

Comment: What type of data are you receiving? How is it formatted? I would assume that this would be the issue. If you can show me the format of the JSON, I might be able to help.

Comment: @jkaufman I have updated the answer to include the JSON data

Comment: Could you please provide the full PHP file? What's your query?

Comment: @jkaufman I have included the php code in the question, please see update

Answer (score 0):

For posting you don't need to make a request, just get content from the url:

```
        var strResult:NSString

        let strURL = "http://localhost/web-service/action.php?callback=showUserDetails&uid=1"

        var dataURL = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strURL)!);

        if let d = dataURL
        {
            strResult = NSString(data: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            println(strResult)

        }
```

Here i simply go to the url, get the content and store it in the data object, and then turning it into a string and printing it. You can also decode the JSON string (strResult) into the JSON object.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey thanks I already managed to get it working but your way is much simpler so I used it :) thanks. Then when would I need to actually send a request ? I initially though I would have to send request if i wanted to retrieve or save data through the web service ...is that incorrect ?

Comment: In your PHP code i can see that you are using GET. For using GET you should give the parameters in a url and data will be echoed. If you want to use HTTP requests you should use POST in PHP rather than GET. This code that i have given is for GET and it works. You can get data like this. If safety is important for you, then you should change the GET method in PHP to the POST method. Like that you will not give parameters through the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method which have completionHandler to get back the result from your web service

```
 func postAsync(backendMethodName:String ,body: [[String:String]], completionHandler: (resultnig:String) -> Void)
{

    let session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let urlPath: String = "\(sessionclass.connectionString)/\(backendMethodName)"

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:urlPath)!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.timeoutInterval=10
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(body, options: [])

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard data != nil else
        {
            print("no data found: \(error)")
            return
        }

        let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        completionHandler(resultnig: strData as! String)


    }

    task.resume()

}
```

its take the backend method Name (in web service) and your jsonData

you can call it like this :

```
 self.postAsync("checkConnection", body: self.alldictionariesConn, completionHandler: { (resultnig) in
       print(resulting) })//resulting = result from your web service
```